# Can an isoSPI interface work without isolation?

Tags: spi, isolation, interference, emi-filtering

Ive got a [LTC6820](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC6820.pdf) that I will be communicating with a LTC6811 and they both use isoSPI but all the example diagrams show the connections going through a transformers and twisted wire like this:

[image: 100M isoSPI connection schematic]

But in that example the wire between was 100m long, but I'm only going 8m tops and it will be in a shielded cable in a low noise environment, so I can't help but wonder if it would work to just have them wired like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYzI1T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect, but cannot confirm that the current regulated driver won't work properly in a direct wiring scheme. Instead, see Figure 18 in the datasheet for a cheap solution vetted to work using capacitive isolation instead.

[image: Figure 18 from LTC6820 datasheet]

From [LTC6820 Datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC6820.pdf).